# Using Image in Android studio "startIconDrawable" is showing grey

Tags: android, android-layout

I am setting a an icon in material TextInputLayout but the icon is showing as grey not its original color(Shown in the image below). Using the same icon image in a Image View is showing colors. I have searched a lot and haven't found any solutions.

[image]

Any help will be great. Thanks in advance.

XML for the TextInputLayout :-

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/country"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/country"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/flag"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+91"
        android:enabled="false"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: can you provide your XML code?

Comment: @YaminYazdanpanah added the xml for that field.

Comment: Maybe it's due to the android:enabled="false"

Comment: @gioravered I removed enabled and checked its still grey. That enabled property is of TextInputEditText but the image is in TextInputLayout ,so it won't have any effect on that.

Comment: What is the flag drawable? Can you post it?

Comment: @Cheticamp I have already tried with many different Image and SVG drawable but it is showing grey but when I use them in ImageView they are colored.

Comment: Remove the style to see if something in there is causing the problem.

Comment: @Cheticamp nothing happens to the flag , the field style changes to default filled text field

Comment: Try setting the tint. `app:startIconTint`. Are these icons always monochrome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply add this line to your xml TextinputLayout Xml file

```
app:startIconTint="@null"


 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/country"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="کشور"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/blue_cheese"
    app:startIconTint="@null">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="+91" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , even though i researched a lot i couldn't find the answer